# Install GDAL on LINUX Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS for python

Tags: python-3.x, installation, gdal, ubuntu-20.04, osgeo

I've been having a lot of problems with this install, especially with various unmet dependencies.
these are my system infos:

**Linux**

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- 64-bit
- Gnome_Version: 3.36.8

**Python**

- using a "poetry environment" (uses pip)
- python Version: 3.8.10

Answer (score 11):

I was finally able to install it more or less cleanly and get it working across the board and hope it will be usefull for others:

#### Installing GDAL on linux is full of problems and issues - this has resolved some of them for me:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

problem depedency with libpq5

```
sudo apt install libpq5=12.2-4

sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

success!

```
sudo apt install gdal-bin

sudo apt install libgdal-dev
```

problem with LOTS of dependencies

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

(aptitude can help resolve dependency problems)

```
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev
```

asks how to resolve issues --> I changed to next reccomendation by pressing "." --> then confirmed by pressing "Y" -->success

##### after these steps are successfull check if all 3 main libs are installed: "libpq-dev, gdal-bin, libgdal-dev":

```
apt list --installed | grep "gdal"
```

result:

---

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gdal-bin/focal,now 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 amd64 [installed]
gdal-data/focal,focal,now 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 all [installed,automatic]
libgdal-dev/focal,now 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 amd64 [installed]
libgdal29/focal,now 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-gdal/focal,now 3.3.2+dfsg-2~focal2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

---

check gdal version (should be 3.3.2 or higher if all went well):

```
gdalinfo --version
```

#### PYTHON

to install gdal in a python environment should now be possible:

```
poetry add gdal==3.3.0
```

or

```
pip install gdal==3.3.0
```

by john, this worked 06.07.2022

Comment: Thank you, I got an error during installation of wradlib that caused by gdal. Now it works for me. Don't forget to accept your answer :)

Comment: Were you using any special repo? When I run `apt list --installed | grep "gdal"` I don't get the same versions as you, and I am indeed using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal.

E.g. first line is: `gdal-bin/focal,now 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 amd64 [installed]`, and the rest are the same 3.0.4.

Comment: I'm on Apple M1 / Silicon, building a linux-based docker image. In case someone else happens upon this and it may help them, I needed to use apt/apt-get to install `gdal-bin` and `libgdal-dev` as the only prerequisites to the python package(s)

Answer (score 0):

This is an add-on to the previous answer, for those who need to compile the source code of a gdal version :

start with https://gdal.org/development/dev_environment.html
then https://gdal.org/development/building_from_source.html

It says that the minimum requirements to build GDAL are:

- CMake >= 3.10, and an associated build system (make, ninja, Visual Studio, etc.)
- C99 compiler
- C++11 compiler

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install build-essential
```

- PROJ >= 6.0

PROJ needs the following dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Download source code of osgeo/PROJ (tar.gz) and build with the same procedure than for GDAL:

```
tar -xvzf proj-9.2.1.tar.gz proj-9.2.1/
cd proj-9.2.1/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
sudo cmake --build . --target install
```

Download source code of osgeo/GDAL (tar.gz -> https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases) and build:
It is necessary to install libgdal-dev

```
sudo apt-get -y install libgdal-dev

tar -xvzf gdal-3.7.0.tar.gz 
cd gdal-3.7.0/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build .
sudo cmake --build . --target install
```