# Unable to Install GDAL 3.4+ on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in Python 3.8 Virtual Environment

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to install **GDAL** (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library) version 3.4 or higher in a Python virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have followed the solution provided in this Stack Overflow post: [Install GDAL on LINUX Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887400/install-gdal-on-linux-ubuntu-20-04-4lts-for-python#comment129799957_72887401). However, despite following the steps, I still end up with GDAL version 3.0.4 instead of the desired version.

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gdal-bin/focal,now 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 amd64 [installed]
gdal-data/focal,focal,now 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 all [installed,automatic]
libgdal-dev/focal,now 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 amd64 [installed]
libgdal26/focal,now 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-gdal/focal,now 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 amd64 [installed]
```

**Environment**:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Python 3.8
PyCharm (with a virtual environment)
```

When I then do:
`pip install gdal==3.0.4`

I get the following error:
`error in GDAL setup command: use_2to3 is invalid. [end of output]`

Comment: Try downgrading setuptools `pip install setuptools==58` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100275/error-while-downloading-the-requirements-using-pip-install-setup-command-use-2

Answer (score 1):

You say you would like to install GDAL 3.4, but you are using `pip install gdal==3.0.4`. Shouldn't it be `pip install gdal==3.4.0`?

On Ubuntu 20.04 the only official GDAL release is `3.0.4+dfsg-1build3`. GDAL 3.4 [is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76862564/2524798) on Ubuntu 22.04 by default. To install GDAL 3.4 on Ubuntu 20.04 you can use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/):

```
mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
```

After restarting the shell install GDAL:

```
conda create -n gdal34 python=3.8 gdal=3.4
```

Now you can check GDAL version

```
conda activate gdal34
gdalinfo --version
```

Execute some python code:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
print(gdal.VersionInfo("–version"))

#> GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
```