# fatal error: proj.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arm, gdal, cgo, proj

I have such errors. I tried all variants, which Google can find out, but it didn`t help.

```
go build cmd/main.go
# github.com/omniscale/go-proj/v2
/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/omniscale/go-proj/v2@v2.0.0-20221006090944-6c8a5f5a510d/proj.go:47:11: fatal error: proj.h: No such file or directory
 // #include <proj.h>
           ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
# github.com/lukeroth/gdal
/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lukeroth/gdal@v0.0.0-20211109203239-b571df3ee436/gdal.go:44:11: cannot define new methods on non-local type C.CPLErr
/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lukeroth/gdal@v0.0.0-20211109203239-b571df3ee436/gdal.go:60:11: cannot define new methods on non-local type C.OGRErr
In file included from /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lukeroth/gdal@v0.0.0-20211109203239-b571df3ee436/algorithms.go:4:0:
./go_gdal.h:8:10: fatal error: gdal.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gdal.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**STEP_1. Trying to solve first error `proj.h: No such file or directory`:**
First of all we need to install PROJ library:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev


root@2cabef130881:/app/src# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease [83.3 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Fetched 261 kB in 1s (205 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
root@2cabef130881:/app/src# apt-get install libproj-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libproj-dev is already the newest version (4.9.3-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After that we should find out file  `proj.h` in our system. We should write a command `find / -name proj.h 2>/dev/null`, but I have no results after that. Typically the `proj.h` file is located in the `/usr/include` directory
But he's not there...

If the `proj.h` file is available, then in our case, `go-proj` should know about the presence of the PROJ library. This is usually configured through the `CGO_CFLAGS` and `CGO_LDFLAGS` environment variables.

In theory it should be:

```
export CGO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"
```

In my code I use import "github.com/omniscale/go-proj/v2" maybe we should write comething new in library ?

**STEP_2. Trying to solve first error `fatal error: gdal.h: No such file or directory**

I tried to solve this problem, like here [Install GDAL on LINUX Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887400/install-gdal-on-linux-ubuntu-20-04-4lts-for-python) but it didnt help.

I tried to fix troubles with gdall library, I installed on OS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

But it didnt help.
Whitch GDAL version I have at present time:

```
apt list --installed | grep "gdal"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gdal-bin/bionic,now 2.2.3+dfsg-2 arm64 [installed]
gdal-data/bionic,now 2.2.3+dfsg-2 all [installed,automatic]
libgdal-dev/bionic,now 2.2.3+dfsg-2 arm64 [installed]
libgdal20/bionic,now 2.2.3+dfsg-2 arm64 [installed,automatic]


gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
```

If we speak about another libraries, which we need to install near GDAL, I installed them in Docker container via command:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -yy && apt-get install -yy \
    wget \
    git \
    build-essential \
    git \
    clang-3.8 \
    libpng-dev \
    libopencv-dev \
    libgeos-dev \
    libproj-dev && \
    apt remove cmake -y && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install cmake --upgrade && \
    apt autoremove -y
```

Version of Ubuntu:

```
 lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I created 2 issues on github, but I din`t think that I will get answers as fast as it possible.